# How to improve a Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial regression model?

Tags: r, regression, glm

everybody!

[image: Distribution of Count Data]

I have a response variable that counts sucessful days in a month and is distributed in a peculiar shape (see above). About 50% are zeros, and there is a heavy tail. Because of the overdispersion and the excess of zeros, I was advised to predict it with a Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial regression model.

However, no matter how significant a model I obtain, it reflects little of those distributing features (see below). For example, the peaks are always around 4, and no predictions fall beyond 20.

[image: Distribution of Predictions]

Is this usual in fitting overdispersed, heavy-tailed count data? Are there other ways to improve the fitting? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

P. S.
I also tried logistic regression to predict zero/non-zero only. But none of the fitted models perform better than simply guessing zeros for all cases.

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes, thanks. https://github.com/PawinData/GLM/blob/master/DATA_cleaned.RData And the response is `menthlth`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you did a histogram of the fitted values, so this will only reflect the fitted means, and possibly multiplied by the ratio of being zero depending on the model you use. It is not supposed to recreate that distribution because how spread your data can be is embedded in the dispersion parameter.

We can use an example from the `pscl` package:

```
library(pscl)
data("bioChemists")
fit <- hurdle(art ~ ., data = bioChemists,dist="negbin",zero.dist="binomial")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

hist(fit$y,main="Observed")
hist(fit$fitted.values,main="Fitted")
```

[image]

As mentioned before, in this hurdle model, the fitted values you see, are the predicted means multiplied by the ratio of being zero (see [more here](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-hurdle-models/)):

```
head(fit$fitted.values)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
1.9642025 1.2887343 1.3033753 1.3995826 2.4560884 0.8783207 

head(predict(fit,type="zero")*predict(fit,type="count"))
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
1.9642025 1.2887343 1.3033753 1.3995826 2.4560884 0.8783207
```

To simulate the data based on the fitted model, we extract out the parameters:

```
Theta=fit$theta
Means=predict(fit,type="count")
Zero_p = predict(fit,type="prob")[,1]
```

Have function to simulate the counts:

```
simulateCounts = function(mu,theta,zero_p){
N = length(mu)
x = rnbinom(N,mu=mu,size=THETA)
x[runif(x)<zero_p] = 0
x
}
```

So run this simulation a number of times to get the spectrum of values:

```
set.seed(100)
simulated = replicate(10,simulateCounts(Means,Theta,Zero_p))
simulated = unlist(simulated)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(bioChemists$art,main="Observed")
hist(simulated,main="simulated")
```

[image]